# Acces mainwindow control from class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know it is something simple.

I have `Mainwindow` which has a textbox. On textbox content change an event happen i.e. `textboxtext_changed` and after that I want textbox to become empty again.

I have a function in other class and it is executed in `textboxtext_changed`. I am thinking of clearing textbox in function in other class only, but I can not access mainwindow controls and I dont want to create instance of mainwindow there.

Is there any easy way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void function(ref TextBox textBox)
{
  textbox.Text = string.empty;
}
```

Comment: where is this function  and how does it solving problem if i put string .empty in textboxtext_changed then it get blank as soon as function executes even  i dont get to see text even it make it blank before that

Answer (score 1):

From your TextChanged function you can access the TextBox from sender

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Text = "";
}
```

Comment: but it never displays text it executes function clear it so fast that i never get to see the content in textbox

Comment: Yes.  Everytime they press a key it all gets erased because we are erasing it.  But I assume you wanted to do something with the text before you let this line execute and erase.  Put your code in before this line executes.

Comment: If you are saying you want to clear the Textbox in the class, but NOT in the TextChanged event then you need to look at Anandkumar's solution above.  Either pass the textbox into the class as a parameter, or setup a textbox property for that class and assign it your textbox as a value so it is available in the class when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

With [MVVM](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=es&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=wpf%20mvvm%20code%20project) it can be very easy:

1. Declare a string property in your ViewModel.
2. Bind the `TextBox.Text` property to this string property and set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged and Mode to TwoWay.
3. Do your logic whenever the property changes on the ViewModel.

**ViewModel**

```
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string someText;

        public string SomeText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.someText;
            }
            set
            {
                this.someText = value;

                if (SomeCondition(this.someText))
                {
                    this.someText = string.Empty;
                }

                var epc = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (epc != null)
                {
                    epc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeText"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```